# gam (from R mgcv package) fitting fails unexplicably

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I'm trying to use gams in R and encountered weird behaviors using Duchon splines.

Here is my code :

```
> fit <- gam(Load ~ s(Date, k=3, bs='ds'), data=data0)
Error in qr.qty(qru, t(qr.qty(qru, D)[-ind, ])) : 
  'qr' and 'y' must have the same number of rows

> fit <- gam(Load ~ s(Date, k=4, bs='ds'), data=data0)
```

data0 is a dataframe of dim 3028, 20
Load and Date are the names of two of the columns of data0 (with numeric values)

Can someone enlight my on why it pass with k>=4 and fails with k=3 ?

In my understanding qr referer to the design matrix of the model and y to the response variable, and there are the same in both cases...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you please include a minimal reproducible example? And, when you have made that, maybe send it to the package maintainer?

Comment: For help with making an R reproducible example:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/469680